# Is there a way to force type onto a value from a list of types?

Tags: python, python-3.x, types

I'm pulling types from elsewhere and I'd like to apply those types to variables. So given a list, for example `[<class 'str'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'float'>]`, is there a way to systematically apply them without setting up a bunch of `if` statements?

```
types = []
for t in ['abc', 1234, 1.2345]:
   types.append(type(t))
print(types)

vars = ['12.34', '56.78', '91.01']
for i in range(len(types)):
   print(<apply types[i] to vars[i]>)
```

output:

```
[<class 'str'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'float'>]
'12.34'
56
91.01
```

Comment: Can you give a more concrete example of your inputs and expected outputs?

Comment: Python is intrinsically a dynamically-typed language, so you can apply a type to a variable as you please. For more specific information, please provide a [mcve] for what you're trying to do, including sample input and output, and code for what you've already tried

Comment: python variables dont have types, only python objects have types and python variables are just references to objects

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy added an example

Comment: "Appyling a type to a variable" does not make any sense, Python variables *do no have types*, Python is a dynamically typed language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`zip` and a list comprehension should do it

```
>>> types = [str, int, float]
>>> values = ["foo", "3", "3.14"]
>>> [t(x) for t, x in zip(types, values)]
["foo", 3, 3.14]
```

Answer (score 2):

A `class` object is callable, so you can do:

```
var = "123"
types = [str, int, float]
result = [typ(var) for typ in types]
print(result) # prints ['123', 123, 123.0]
```

Comment: that's not what my types input looks like

Comment: You edited the question. chepner's answer works for your input.

Comment: no it doesn't ... `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '56.78'`

Comment: You can't apply the `int` type to a string that doesn't look like a valid integer.

Comment: oh, derp, that makes sense %\